# Responsive Set width and height to 80%

Tags: html, css, height, width

I have a problem for set responsive width and height to a container.

I need to set height and width of the container in 80% of my screen, but thats not work (i think because body have no height and width).

thats an exemple code :

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
    </div>
</div>

#container
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    padding:5px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.box
{
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    background-color:red;
}

.element
{
    width:22.5%;
    height:96%;
    margin:1%;
    background-color:yellow;
    float:left;
}
```

Thats the JSFIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/trsjc7cw/

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
#container {

  width: 80vw;

  height: 80vh;

  background-color: blue;

  padding: 5px;

  margin: auto;

}

.box {

  width: 100%;

  height: 50%;

  background-color: red;

}

.element {

  width: 22.5%;

  height: 96%;

  margin: 1%;

  background-color: yellow;

  float: left;

}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

use **vw and vh** units!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's work perfectly ! I never use it so i doesn't know this, it's very useful !

Comment: Thanks for the link, i have check and i think it's ok because i want to put this on a webview with phonegap and it's o for mobile brownser, only old android version don't support this. Do you know how can i do for force "element" to be always square (same height and width) ?  thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should only need a wrapper around your `<div>` that is 100 view width and 100 view height.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="box">
             <div class="element"></div>
             <div class="element"></div>
             <div class="element"></div>
             <div class="element"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="element"></div>
            <div class="element"></div>
            <div class="element"></div>
            <div class="element"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



#wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
#container {
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
}
```

You can also use your body as the wrapper. Just make sure that you set the height and width of the `<body>` and `<html>` elements to 100% in the css.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, how can i do for force "element" to be always square (same height and width) ?