# How to make div always 80% of page height and completely square?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, responsive

I understand that this is a confusing question but I can't think of a better way to word it! Basically, I need a div element to always be 80% of the height of the page, and have the div's width always be the same width as the height (not 80% of the page width, but rather, the same length as 80% of the page's height, so that the div is square.) I've researched quite a bit and have yet to figure out a way to do this. I'm open to using JS but would prefer to use only CSS to accomplish this. Here is essentially how I want my layout to look at several different page heights/aspect ratios:
[MY PAGE LAYOUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II9sX.jpg)

The blue div should be 80% of the page height and should *always be square*.
The reason I need this is because I want the page to never have a scrollbar, so the div must be responsive to the page height, but I also want the div to be a perfect square.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider using [view height/width units](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/), like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089994/responsive-set-width-and-height-to-80

Answer (score 8):

You can use vh -> 1vh being equal to 1% of the height of the viewport's initial containing block.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

So your class would be something like:

```
.yourClass {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vh;
}
```

Comment: For `width` I would go for `80vw` to get 80% of viewport width.

Comment: question was 80% of height and square. using 80vw would make not make it square

Answer (score 4):

You can declare both width and height in `vh` units, which represents 1% of the viewport height. In this case, that'd be

```
div{
  width:80vh;
  height:80vh;
}
```

That being said, it's a really bad approach. If the viewport height ever gets bigger than the width (e.g. on any mobile, or a resized window), you'll get horizontal scrollbars or hidden, overflowing content.

For such case, it'd be much better to use `vmin`, which is 1% of whatever the smaller viewport dimension

```
div{
  width:80vMin;
  height:80vMin;
}
```

Alternatively you can use media queries to detect if the viewport is at landscape (wide) or portrait (tall) mode

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  div{
    width:80vh;
    height:80vh;
  }
}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  div{
    width:80vw;
    height:80vw;
   /*or whatever*/
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the solution! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.equalSize {
  width: 80vh;
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="equalSize"><div>
```

You can use css build in units. vh = viewport height
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Another option would be to use aspect ratio like explained here: [Aspect ratio](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp)